# audio and video out of sync nextlevel iOS lib

Tags: ios, swift

We are using NextLevel iOS video recording library 0.8.4 (https://github.com/nextlevel/NextLevel/) and find that at times we are receiving video that is not synced with the audio. We don't believe its version specific as this issue has cropped up since we built the app in early August 2017.

Currently app is running only on iOS 11. Unfortunately haven't been able to reproduce or narrow down to specific iPhone model. Using Swift version 4.0.

We allow users to create 30 second video captures with both fwd/rear facing cameras. They hold a button to record the video, then when 30 seconds has passed or when they release record button and click a Submit UI button, we then call an export function, similar to this:

```
func exportVideo() {
  guard let session = NextLevel.shared.session else {
    return
  }

  session.mergeClips(usingPreset: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality) { [weak self] (url, error) in
    self?.hideLoading()

    guard let strongSelf = self, let url = url, error == nil else {
      self?.showAlert(with: error)
      return
    }

    strongSelf.delegate?.videoCaptureViewController(strongSelf, didSendEvent: .capturedVideo(withURL: url))
  }
}
```